# How to show a text in tkinter Entry widget while checkbutton is unchecked

Tags: python, tkinter

while creating a check button for hiding and unhiding the text in a password field on a Entry widget , how can i show a text in tkinter Entry widget while checkbutton is unchecked

```
def show():
    password_entry.config(show="")


password_entry = Entry(show="*")
password_entry.pack()

showpassword = Checkbutton(text="Show Password",command=show)
showpassword.pack()
```

how shall i describe the function def Show(): ?

the above code works but when i uncheck the button it dosent hides the text .

Comment: Probably missing  `Intvar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the on and off values of the checkbutton to `""` and `"*"`, then use a tkinter variable to get the value and use it to configure the entry. It would look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def show():
    show = show_password_var.get()
    password_entry.configure(show=show)

root = tk.Tk()
show_password_var = tk.StringVar(root, value="*")
password_entry = tk.Entry(root)
show_password = tk.Checkbutton(text="Show Password", command=show, onvalue="", offvalue="*", variable=show_password_var)

password_entry.pack()
show_password.pack()

show()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: U're right. It was my mistaken not `IntVar()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `show` option of the `Entry` widget to either `""` or `"*"` based on the check state of the checkbutton.

In order to get the check state of the checkbutton, you need to associate a `BooleanVar` or `IntVar` to it:

```py
def show():
    password_entry.config(show="" if show_var.get() else "*")

...
show_var = BooleanVar()
showpassword = Checkbutton(text="Show Password", variable=show_var, command=show)
...
```